# Javascript Image Preload with 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to preload some images here. But what i need is to preload some images in an array, and show the progress.

This is working, but its giving me the **GET 404 (Not Found)** in console. But its working. What can i do to avoid this warning?

thanks!

```
function start(id) {
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = "http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_fiji_sunset_wallpaper.jpg";
    images[1] = "http://www.fantasy-and-art.com/wp-content/gallery/abstract-wallpapers/lion_hd_wallpaper.jpg";
    images[2] = "http://hidefwallpaper.org/wp-content/gallery/1_apple_wallpaper_02/90831582ea8e018759044f2820b518d1.jpg";
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = images[id];
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        if (id == images.length) {
            alert('Carregou tudo');
        }
        if (id < images.length) {
            start(id + 1);
            alert(id);
        }
    }
}
start(0);​
```

Comment: Make sure you bind the onload event before you set the src. It won't fix this issue, but it will allow cached images to work properly in IE <9

Comment: Why are you re-building the array every time through the function? Wouldn't it make sense to have that chunk outside of the function?

Comment: @j08691 Thats make sense. I updated my code.

Comment: @MarkLinus Didnt work man. Same issue.

Comment: @KevinB Yea, but my priority its to fix the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call of your start function is executing one too many times which is why you'd get the 404 message as there is no array element with an index equal to the length of the array. Arrays are zero-based. So for example, when you call `if (id < images.length) {` when id is two, you increment id to 3 and call start again, however there is no images[3].

Try this:

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_fiji_sunset_wallpaper.jpg";
images[1] = "http://www.fantasy-and-art.com/wp-content/gallery/abstract-wallpapers/lion_hd_wallpaper.jpg";
images[2] = "http://hidefwallpaper.org/wp-content/gallery/1_apple_wallpaper_02/90831582ea8e018759044f2820b518d1.jpg";

function start(id) {
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = images[id];
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        if (id == images.length) {
            console.log('Carregou tudo');
        }
        if (id < (images.length-1)) {
            start(id + 1);
        }
    }
}
start(0);​
```

Comment: Yea, i tried your code and it gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Not working when you put it in your site or not working in the jsFiddle?

Comment: No. images length is 3. And your code was pointing to if id was same ans images length. I modified, and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/kVL22/. Thanks a lot man! :)

Comment: I just left that in there from your original code. I had no idea what you need it for, however good that you learned how to take the example and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

first set the images array...
then.

```
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    imgsrc = images[i];
    var obj = new Image();
    obj.src = imgsrc;
    obj.id = i;
    obj.onload = function(){
       if(this.id == images.length-1){
          alert('Carregou tudo');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously replace imageObj = new Image() until the end of the function with this. Start now doesn't need any parameters. It will load all of them, and alert once the 3rd one is ready. You can also keep a counter and alert once the counter has reached images.length, so you know when all images are loaded

Comment: this.id will never equal images.length, ids are 0,1,2 for example and length will be 3.

Comment: Oh right Well that's a stupid but insignificant mistake. Replace with length-1 and your good to go

Comment: & also, this is set to the object when it's onload function is triggered.